# Is Windows' rand_s thread-safe?

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, random

Just as in title. Is suspect it is, but I couldn't find it anywhere explicitly stated. And for this property I wouldn't like to rely on speculations.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use the [multithreaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh(VS.80).aspx) version of the CRT, all functions are thread safe, because any thread-specific information is stored in [TLS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686749.aspx). rand_s actually doesn't use state information in the first place, since it just calls an OS API, so question of thread-safety doesn't arise for rand_s. rand(), however depends on a seed value to generate a random number.

Answer (score 3):

Chris said: `rand()` is not thread-safe because its internal state is static, but `rand_s()` should be thread-safe, however.

Jeff added however that with the multithreaded version of MSVCRT, `rand()`'s state is held in thread-local storage, so it's okay still.

Comment: According to: http://hype-free.blogspot.com/2008/05/multi-threaded-visual-c-rand.html
rand() stores its state in the TLS, meaning it's thread-safe from the VC environment (which is implied by the specific question regarding rand_s()).

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio comes with the source to the runtime library.  While some of it can be rather painful to wade through, rand_s() is pretty simple.

All rand_s() does is call SystemFunction036() in ADVAPI32.DLL to get the random value.  Anything in ADVAPI32.DLL should be thread-safe.

For its part, rand_s() gets the pointer to that function in a thread-safe manner.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if rand_s is thread-safe, but it seems like it probably is, since it seems to make a round-trip to the OS for entropy. (as long as you link to the VC++ multi-thread CRT, all bets are off if you link to the single-thread one)

If it's supported by windows CRT, you can try a call to rand_r which is the posix reentrant version of rand. OR even better boost::random, if you're already using boost.

considering how pervasive multi-threading will be soon, no one should be using rand() anymore in new code - always try to use rand_r/rand_s/boost/various platform-dependent secure rands/etc.

Answer (score -2):

I can't think of any reason why rand_s() or even rand() wouldn't be thread safe.

Comment: Okay, but it's still a speculation. For example rand() stores its current seed in a variable shared by all threads... And in POSIX there are special functions that are designed for use inside threads.

Comment: rand() is not thread-safe, because its internal state in static, like phjr mentioned. rand_s() should be thread-safe, however.

Comment: As I responded to Simucal, the VC runtime apparently enforces static variables being stored in the TLS, meaning rand() is as completely thread safe as rand_s().