# VS rand() problem with pthread-win32

Tags: c++, visual-studio, random, pthreads

I come into a strange problem in pthread programming
I've compiled the following code in vs2005 with [pthread-w32](http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/)

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <windows.h>

pthread_mutex_t lock;

void* thread1(void *) {
  int r1;
  while(true) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock); // rand is maybe a CS
    r1 = rand() % 1500;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    Sleep(r1); printf("1:%d\n", r1);
  }
  return NULL;
}

void* thread2(void *) {
  int r2;
  while(true) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    r2 = rand() % 1500;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    Sleep(r2); printf("2:%d\n", r2);
  }
  return NULL;
}

int main() {
  srand((int)time(NULL));
  pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL);

  pthread_t tc_p, tc_v;
  pthread_create(&tc_p, NULL, thread1, NULL);
  pthread_create(&tc_v, NULL, thread2, NULL);

  pthread_join(tc_p, NULL);
  pthread_join(tc_v, NULL);

  pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);

    return 0;
}
```

and output is like this

```
2:41
1:41
1:467
2:467
1:334
2:334
1:1000
2:1000
```

it's just like that rand() is return the same result in every two calls
and i have srand() but the result doesn't change each time i run the program

i'm very new to multi thread programming and i've heard about the rand() is not thread safe. but i still can't figure out if the program above is wrong or the rand() function has some problem in it.

Comment: Related SO question: [Is Windows’ rand_s thread-safe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143108/is-windows-rand-s-thread-safe)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`rand` is only pseudo-random, and will return the same sequence each time.  `srand` only works on the current thread, so calling it in your main thread won't affect your worker threads.

You need to call `srand` from within each thread, with a value that's different for each thread - for instance, within your `thread1` and `thread2` functions:

```
srand((int)time(NULL) ^ (int)pthread_getthreadid_np());
```

Comment: thanks a lot
but I wonder why srand() only works on current thread?

Comment: probably uses thread-local storage - each thread will have its own copy of the random number seed

Answer (score 1):

Try using `rand_s()` instead, it is thread-safe. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxtz2fa8(VS.80).aspx). Of course, it's not portable.