# C open mp wrong calculation without print

Tags: c, for-loop, parallel-processing, openmp, pragma

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<omp.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

float FloatRandomizer(float a, float b)
{
    float randomNumber = (a + (float)rand() / (float)(RAND_MAX / b));

    if (randomNumber > b)
        randomNumber = randomNumber - a;

    return randomNumber;
}

float F(float x)
{
    return x * x;
}


int main()
{
    int n = 1000000;

    float a;
    printf("a = "); scanf_s("%f", &a);

    float b;
    printf("b = "); scanf_s("%f", &b);

    float temp = (b - a) / n;

    float sum = 0;
    int i;

#pragma omp parallel for shared(sum)
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        float randomNumber = FloatRandomizer(a, b);
        sum = sum + F(randomNumber);
        //printf("threadNum = %d\nsum = %f\n", omp_get_thread_num(), sum);
    }

    float result = temp * sum;
    printf("result = %f", result);
}
```

There are not to much things to say. I am trying to get definite integral within given [a,b] range with Monte-Carlo method. So basically everything works, problems started when I wrote `#pragma open mp for` statement, it calculates result(that for `a = 0` and `b = 1` should be `1/3`) in wrong way without commented line within `for` loop but with `printf` it calculates it correctly. I can't understand the problem

Without `printf`:

[image]

With `printf` for same `a` and `b`(last line of big output):

[image]

I am using Microsoft Windows 10 and Microsoft Visual Studio.

Comment: The function `rand` is not guaranteed to be thread-safe. I suggest that you use a platform-specific function which is guaranteed to be thread-safe, for example [`rand_r`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/srand.3.html) on Linux. Every thread should have its own state of the random number generator.

Comment: On the other hand, I believe that when using the Microsoft C runtime library, the function `rand` is thread-safe, because the documentation does not mention anywhere that it is not thread-safe. Therefore, please specify in the question which platform (i.e. which operating system and compiler) you are using.

Comment: In addition, `sum = sum + ...;` is not thread safe (sum is dependent of the part value and there is no lock nor atomic addition). You need a reduction. There are at least dozens of OpenMP posts about this, tutorials and examples for both the reduction and the rand problem. Please read some of them.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel It uses a global state by default for the whole application so it is certainly not thread safe. This is mention [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/rand?view=msvc-170): "*By default, this function's global state is scoped to the application*".

Comment: @JérômeRichard: If `rand` is implemented in such a way that access to the global state is protected by a mutex, then it would be thread-safe. As far as I can tell, the Microsoft documentation does not specify whether this is the case or not.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel It would be stupid to me to protect rand using a mutex since a multithreaded usage of rand would be very inefficient due to a cache line bouncing and there will still be a race condition while using srand... Not to mention it would make rand slower also in sequential. Thus, yes this is theoretically true but unlikely to be the case. At least, I hope they do not implement it that way. One can check the assembly code at runtime to be sure.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel OS is Win 10 and compiler is Visual Studio's Local Windows Debugger

Comment: @JérômeRichard: You may be correct. On the other hand, the function `fgetc` is implemented in such a way that it does acquire a mutex, because the ISO C standard requires that function to be thread-safe. Therefore, it would not be surprising to me if Microsoft decided to implement `rand` in the same way, even if ISO C does not require that function to be thread-safe.

Comment: @JérômeRichard: According to the answers and comments in [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143108/is-windows-rand-s-thread-safe), `rand` uses thread-local storage in the multithreaded version of the library, so it is thread-safe. The single-threaded version is no longer available, except in older versions.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel `fgetc` is an IO function so it is not much a problem to use a lock in it. It seems reasonable to me, especially since this function is inherently inefficient due to the non-buffering. This is different for `rand` (especially since it is explicitly not required to be thread-safe by the standard). Using the TLS for the MT version make sense. That being said, this MT flag is not enabled by default so the OP certainly did not use it. Besides, I think it is not a good idea to rely on platform specific implementation. In fact, using rand in a critical loop is actually not a good idea

Comment: If one need to generate random numbers efficiently, then it is important to use an SIMD-friendly implementation of a PRNG. The resulting code should be several time faster (possibly up to 8 times faster on a mainstream machine with AVX-2 or even 16 times on future machine and few computing servers).

Comment: @JérômeRichard: In your comment, you wrote: `"That being said, this MT flag is not enabled by default so the OP certainly did not use it."` -- Which "MT flag" are you talking about? I am unaware of any such flag.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I was referring to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/md-mt-ld-use-run-time-library?view=msvc-170) one. The MD flag seems also Ok (though AFAIK accessing TLS variables is slower in dynamic libraries, like for Linux shared libraries).