Does each thread have its own copy of the `rand()` prng?
I was playing around with some simple C++ code for an exam question about threading, where the threads were calling rand() (and yes, I am aware there are good reasons to use other generators, but wanted to keep the exam question simple and to-the-point). The code was using srand() to seed the prng before creating the threads, but I was surprised to notice that every thread was getting the same sequence of numbers from the prng (independently) as if it hadn't been seeded (or rather seeded with 1 as is the default). It was not until I started seeding the prng in each thread that the sequence changed.
I know that rand() is not thread-safe, so I'm not exactly surprised that the threads would all get the same sequence (as I imagine the generator would need some cache syncing to avoid that), but I am surprised that seeding the prng in the host process before creating the threads does not seem to have any effect on the sequence.
For example, in a comment to this question:
Threads, how to seed random number generator independently?
it is stated that you should "not seed your generator in the threads. Seed it before starting any thread. The generator you are using with rand() and srand() is unique for the whole program."
So my question is this:
Does each thread get a separate copy of the generator, or why does seeding it in the host process not affect the sequence?
A minimal code example reproducing the issue follows.
I am aware these are not good seeds or best practice, but it demonstrates what I'm talking about.
When I run this (no seeding at all):
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;

void test(int id, mutex &channel)
{
    // srand(id);

    channel.lock();
    cout << id << ": " << rand() % 1000 << endl;
    channel.unlock();

    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(100));

    channel.lock();
    cout << id << ": " << rand() % 1000 << endl;
    channel.unlock();
}

int main()
{
    // srand(5);
    cout << rand() % 1000 << endl;
    cout << rand() % 1000 << endl;

    int n = 4;
    thread threads[n];
    mutex output_channel;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        threads[i] = thread(test, i, ref(output_channel));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        threads[i].join();
    }

    return 0;
}

I get this:
41
467
0: 41
1: 41
2: 41
3: 41
3: 467
2: 467
0: 467
1: 467

When I run this (only seeding once):
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;

void test(int id, mutex &channel)
{
    // srand(id);

    channel.lock();
    cout << id << ": " << rand() % 1000 << endl;
    channel.unlock();

    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(100));

    channel.lock();
    cout << id << ": " << rand() % 1000 << endl;
    channel.unlock();
}

int main()
{
    srand(5);
    cout << rand() % 1000 << endl;
    cout << rand() % 1000 << endl;

    int n = 4;
    thread threads[n];
    mutex output_channel;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        threads[i] = thread(test, i, ref(output_channel));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        threads[i].join();
    }

    return 0;
}

I get this:
54
693
0: 41
1: 41
2: 41
3: 41
2: 467
3: 467
0: 467
1: 467

which is what I find surprising.
As you see, the threads exhibit the same behavior as when there's no seeding.
And when I run this (seeding in each thread):
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;

void test(int id, mutex &channel)
{
    srand(id);

    channel.lock();
    cout << id << ": " << rand() % 1000 << endl;
    channel.unlock();

    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(100));

    channel.lock();
    cout << id << ": " << rand() % 1000 << endl;
    channel.unlock();
}

int main()
{
    // srand(5);
    cout << rand() % 1000 << endl;
    cout << rand() % 1000 << endl;

    int n = 4;
    thread threads[n];
    mutex output_channel;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        threads[i] = thread(test, i, ref(output_channel));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        threads[i].join();
    }

    return 0;
}

I get this:
41
467
0: 38
1: 41
2: 45
3: 48
2: 216
3: 196
0: 719
1: 467

which achieves independent randomization in the threads (and one could easily produce better seeds etc.), but I would like to understand the reason for the behavior witnessed above.
In case it's relevant, I'm running this on Windows 10 on a dual-core machine (Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7600U CPU), compiling with g++.

rand is global.  it's not meant to be used in multithreading and even in single thread applications should be avoided.  Use the modern <random> header and if you want each thread to have its own PRNG then create the PRNG object in the thread.

It is implementation-defined whether rand() is thread-safe. MS: By default, this function's global state is scoped to the application.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/143119/1387438 - so depending on CRT library version you can get thread local storage of seed - can't find explicit MS documentation about this :/ the link I provided earlier just says not thread safe, but looks like this applies for older version of CRT library.

Don't expect much from rand. It was designed in the 1970s to solve 1970s problems on 1970s hardware. And watch out with int n = 4; thread threads[n];. n isn't a compile-time constant, so threads is not a Standard-approved array. No guarantee that it'll compile on a given implementation, and if it does, you'll have to consult the implementation documentation to see what kind of gotchas lurk around the edges. Easily avoided with const int n = 4; or constexpr int n = 4;

It's very simple: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand says "It is implementation-defined whether rand() is thread-safe". If you want to be sure, use the more advanced mechanisms that C++ provides, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

@NathanOliver
Thank you. I'm aware that using <random> should be preferred, but as I said, I wanted to keep the code short, avoiding unnecessarily detail about choice of algorithms as the focus wasn't the random number generation. I was basically using rand() as pseudo-code in this instance.
But I just got curious as to why this was not working as I expected, and couldn't seem to find any explanation in the docs or on SO or elsewhere.

@MarekR
Ok, so you're saying this would depend on the implementation, and someone else running the above code might get results where the initial seeding would actually affect the sequences received by the threads?

@ChristianStieber
Thank you. To clarify, what I would like to understand is how exactly it happens that the threads get access to an unseeded prng when the generator has been explicitly seeded before the threads are created.

There is an aspect you're overlooking: Hardware is magic.
You've seeded srand in one thread, and the CPU running that thread updated the globals, which were written to that CPU's private L1 cache.
Then your code spawned new threads, each of which tried to read from those same globals.  From RAM.  And thus read the value from before the write.
Reads and writes using locks or atomic will use special CPU instructions forcing writes to shared caches/RAM, and special CPU instructions forcing reads to read from shared caches/RAM, but since your rand implementation isn't thread-safe (and thus this is undefined behavior), the compiler did not emit those instructions, and thus the values read and written by different threads are inconsistent.

Ah yes, that explains it. Thank you!

This can't be the true. L1 cache would give none deterministic consistency for each thread. Also when he seeded generator in main  then started thread all new threads should see this, if this would be L1 cache issue, but it doesn't happen. I'm lining into explanation to SO answer I linked https://stackoverflow.com/a/143119/1387438 which proper version of standard library used TLS (which perfectly explains observed behavior). Since I can't find MS documentation about that I just posted this as a comment.

Note also that his code uses mutexes so this add memory barriers.

@MarekR
Ah yes, you're right. I overlooked the TLS relevance on my first read of your link.
I agree, this better explains why all threads start the sequence from the beginning, even though I have more threads than cores.

@MarekR : I hadn't noticed the memory barriers. your explanation makes way more sense.

The wording in the C standard is slightly unclear, but we it seems like srand() is not required to have an immediate inter-thread effect.
Note that [c.math.rand] p2 delegates semantics of rand() and srand() to C, and C says:

The srand function uses the argument as a seed for a new sequence of pseudo-random numbers
to be returned by subsequent calls to rand.

- 7.22.2.2, paragraph 2
Subsequent is an informal term, and it's unclear whether this refers to rand() calls that are sequenced after calls to srand() (i.e. subsequent on the same thread), or to calls that happen after calls to srand() (i.e. subsequent between threads).
Judging by the fact that rand() and srand() are "not required to avoid data races", it's safe to say if the standard library chooses not to make rand() thread-safe, srand() is also not required to have some inter-thread seeding effect.
In practice, if you call srand(5) and rand() on the same thread, the compiler might just assume that rand() will have a seed of 5 without actually reading the PRNG state.
The write to the PRNG state might be hold off for a very long time.
It's also possible that a call to srand(5) does write to the PRNG state shared by all threads, but other threads use their own cached value (CPU-cached or software-cached) of the PRNG state for a very long time instead of the recently written seed.
In short, things get very weird when there is no synchronization between threads and they share state.

Note: Another reason why this wording is slightly defective is that even if rand avoids data races, it's unclear how its state is shared/synchronized between threads.
Intuitively, it should behave like an atomic read-modify-write operation when it's thread-safe, but nothing states that.

Interesting, thanks!
I was assuming that the effect of srand() would be seen by the other threads because they are only created after the seeding, so their own cached values of the PRNG state does not come into existence until after the prng has been seeded in the host thread. But apparently, when the threads are created, they don't inherit the prng state from the host process as I thought, but rather some preexisting version of it. I suppose my mistake was assuming the host process seeding would influence this preexisting version due to the fact that there was only one thread at that time.

All of the libc implementations with which I am familiar use a single global variable to hold the LCG state of rand().
If you want to avoid the single global state, use the C++ <random> library instead. You can place those generator object in thread-local storage.

OP is not trying to avoid a single global state.

Sure. They're wondering why implementation-defined behaviour is defined differently on different implementations.

No, they're wondering why the threads are time-traveling. They're only looking at a single implementation.

Exactly. I didn't realize the seed would not make it all the way to the state the threads would share, in time. Thank you both for your input :)
